# Docker container doesn't run until I click "Enable volumes" in Kitematic

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, kitematic

I recently created a docker-compose file here: https://github.com/ffMathy/Screeps.Server.Docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

I'm currently on Windows, but running Linux containers.

When I try to start up my containers using `docker-compose up`, they appear just fine. However, the `screeps` container doesn't show anything in the log, and doesn't start (I know this because I can't connect to its port).

**Now, if I then click the volume via Kitematic (as shown in the screenshot) and click "Enable volumes" in the prompt that shows, the container restarts, and works - logs are also present in the preview as expected.**

[image]
[image]

I don't understand how this can affect the container itself - that doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by forcing the volume to mount to a relative path in my `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same exact issue.

Downgrade Kitematic to 0.17.6 seems to fix the problem.

You can download it from here:

https://github.com/docker/kitematic/releases/tag/v0.17.6

Comment: This resolved the logging issue, but not the issue causing container to not start unless I click "Enable volumes".

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Is this for a specific container or for everyone?

Comment: There might be an error/typo in the docker-compose file: The volume screeps-volume is defined but not actually used. What is used is a local directory: "./screeps-volume". Could you fix the file to use the actual volume by removing the "./" part and try again?